# MySQL Stored Proc Refactoring - Extract Method

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, refactoring

I have some logic in a stored procedure (MySQL) that is calculating 8 variables that I now want to reuse this logic is another stored procedure. I want to 'extract method' this piece of logic in to a separate stored proc and then call it and store the results in the caller, in perhaps a temporary table. Does anyone know of a pattern to do this?

I've read up that you can can't store any results when you simply CALL proc_name(); etc, so I'm wondering what the most elegant way of doing this is?

Thanks.

Comment: `Calculating 8 variables`? Does this mean setting / determining 8 scalar values? If you want to reuse the logic that sets/ determines 8 scalar values, you could make those variables `OUT` parameters and avoid the use of temporary tables.

Comment: Thanks AgRizzo, that's what I've gone with. Yes, they are just INT(11)'s, so OUT params seems to be fine and easy to maintain in this case. :)